# Forward to a servlet from another servlet or from a filter

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

Usually I forward to a jsp or to a mapped URL from a servlet, and internet is full of such examples. But I need to forward a request to an internal servlet. For example by using its full class name, without mapping that servlet to an URL. How to forward a request to an internal servlet from another servlet, or from a filter?

Comment: i doubt you can use any servlet without mapping it to a url.The simplest thing that can be done is to use @WebServlet annotation instead of mapping it in the deployement descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

As Shadab commented, I think you should use @WebServlet annotation (and RequestDispatcher), for example:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/sample" })
public class SampleServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = req.getRequestDispatcher( "/forwardpath");
    dispatch.forward(req, res);
}
```

SampleServlet -> ForwardedServlet

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/forwardpath" })
public class ForwardedServlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you want is `RequestDispatcher   getNamedDispatcher(String name);` that  returns a RequestDispatcher object that acts as a wrapper for the named servlet.

And the javadoc for `ServletConfig.getServletName()` says:

> The name may be provided via server administration, assigned in the web application deployment descriptor, or for an unregistered (and thus unnamed) servlet instance it will be the servlet's class name.

You you just have to do:

```
getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher("full.class.name.for.new.servlet");
```